# How to set dynamic background image of a div ONLY if an image is present in the database

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to have dynamic background images for multiple divs through index.html.erb, and have accomplished this through inline styling with the background URL being pulled from my database (using carrierwave). It looks something like this right now:

```
 <div class="style-box col-8 ml-auto mr-auto" style="background: url(<%= place.photos.first.picture.url %>)">
      <h1><%= link_to place.name, place_path(place) %></h1>
      <i><%= place.address %></i>
      <br /><br />
      <p><%= place.description %></p>
```

The issue I'm running into is that, when a new place is created, if an image for the new place isn't present (which it wont be immediately upon creation), the view can't create the full html page with incomplete data (ie. place.photos is nil). Is there a way, using this method or something similar, to make the background image overide the default style-box background ONLY if an image for a new place is present? Typically I'd use an if statement, but can't think of a way to make an if statement update CSS with rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep everything inline you can do:

```rb
<div class="style-box col-8 ml-auto mr-auto"
    style="background: url(<%= place.photos.first&.picture.url || "/images/default.jpg" %>)">
    <h1><%= link_to place.name, place_path(place) %></h1>
    <i><%= place.address %></i>
    <br /><br />
    <p><%= place.description %></p>
</div>
```

This is using the or operator (`||`) which lets the first value through if present, or the second as a default. Also, the `&` will keep the page from having errors if there are no photos. This is essentially the same as writing:

```
style="background: url(
    <% if place.photos.first&.picture&.url %>
        <%= place.photos.first&.picture&.url %>
    <% else %>
        /images/default.jpg
    <% end %>
)">
```

You could also move this into a helper method to let you clean things up, something like:

```rb
# in one of the app/helpers modules
def picture_url_or_default(place, default_url = '/images/default.jpg')
    return default_url if place.photos.empty
    return default_url if place.photos.first.picture.nil?
    return default_url if place.photos.first.picture.url.nil?

    place.photos.first.picture.url
end

# in the view
<div class="style-box col-8 ml-auto mr-auto"
    style="background: url(<%= picture_url_or_default(place))">

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about using || and & for inline styling. great write up.